# Laravel Localization on Laravel 6.9

Tags: php, laravel, localization

As in the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/localization)  I have configured my application as below to change languages.

1. Created sub-directories inside the resources lang folder with each directory contain a messages.php file with relevant languages. Like below

   /resources

   ```
   /lang
       /si
           messages.php
       /ta
           messages.php
   ```
2. Then made a get route as in the documentation and it's same as in the documentation

   ```
     Route::get('change-lang/{locale}', function ($locale) {

       if (! in_array($locale, ['en', 'si', 'ta'])) {
           abort(400);
       }

       (dd(App::getLocale()); // this gives me the default lang en

       App::setLocale($locale);

       // (dd(App::getLocale()); // this gives me the setted language
   });
   ```

This is the first time I'm using this `setLocale()` method. Usually, I used to change the language via passing additional parameters with each route and when I did it it's working fine. But I want to make new application with  `setLocale()` method since it is very easy to woking. So I have done everything according to the documentation but still, the language doesn't get changed.

Can anybody please help me to fix this.

Comment: how are you calling the translation strings?

Comment: @IGP `{{ __( messages.stringname) }}`

Comment: Refreshing the view does nothing? Is there a `meta` tag with the `lang` attribute?

Comment: yes, there is. No refreshing doesn't change anything. As in the question if I change the language via assign additional parameter then it's working. I'm ok with the old method. But need to work with this new method.